# Can you pass the value of Apex: outputLink to Javascript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Using apex:outputLink you can link to record IDs. I would like to access a record through a JQuery click function. Is there a way to pass the value of the outputLink to javascript?

```
function clickTables()
{

     ('.propertyRateTable').click(function()
     {
         //OPEN LINK FROM COMMAND LINK
     });
}
```

Output Link:

```
<apex:outputLink id="hkLink" value="/{!hk.id}" target="_blank">{!hk.Property__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

EDIT

```
<div id="leftBottomBlock">                                
            <apex:pageBlock id="todayReport" title="Today's Reports">
                <div id="hkRecords">
                    <apex:outputLabel ><strong>Properties:</strong></apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!hk_records}" var="hk" id="hkRecordList">
                        <div class="propertyRateDiv">
                            <table class="hkRecordTable">
                                <apex:outputLink id="hkLink" value="/{!hk.id}" target="_blank">{!hk.Property__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Supervisor: </td>
                                        <td>{!hk.Supervisor__c}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>........
```

Comment: Could you include a code snippet of what you've done (tried) so far? The answer to your question is generally "yes", but you'll get a much better answer if you can provide a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited my post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<apex:outputLink>` is rendered as a normal `a` tag, so you can bind to it normally, like this:

```
$('.propertyRateTable').on('click','a', function(e) {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" />
    <script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
        $j('.pageBlockTable').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            alert('This link goes to the URL: '+$j(this).attr('href'));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="record" styleClass="pageBlockTable">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!record.id}">{!record.name}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Ahh good to know. May I just ask what the 'e' represents? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexBrigham you can call it whatever you want, but `e` is the traditional value used. It's the event that was triggered (e.g. this was a MouseEvent, so `e` contains details about the target, the mouse cursor's position, etc).

Comment: Hey, I still cannot get this to work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @AlexBrigham Allow me to write up some example code; maybe that will help you out.

Comment: @AlexBrigham I wrote a minimalist version that works. Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: I still was not able to get it working, but we also wrote the VisualForce differently. I've edited the post to show mine, do you see anything wrong? PS. I am using the class 'hkRecordTable' instead of 'propertyRateTable'

Comment: Silly question... Did you use the ready function, as shown in my code? You need to make sure the Dom is loaded first...

Comment: Yep, I had a ready function to begin with. Funny enough though after replicating your code, I realized that using a pageBlockTable for my use case works a lot better than a standard HTML table. With the new layout, I won't be using any jquery to open the link. Thanks for putting time into this though, I did learn a couple things! :)